# I want to animate my pin on the map i wrote the code but it's doing nothing

Tags: objective-c

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)GUmap:(MKMapView *)GUmap viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView =(MKPinAnnotationView *) [GUmap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pinView"];


if (pinView==nil)
{
    pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"];
    pinView.pinColor= MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
 }
else
{
   pinView.annotation = annotation;
}
return pinView;
}
```

This should animate my pin but it's doing nothing i'll be thankful if you solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method is named incorrectly as `GUmap:viewForAnnotation:` so the map view isn't calling it and is creating a default pin which does not animate the drop.

Change the method declaration to:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)GUmap viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
                     ^^^^^^^
```

It's OK to use a different name for the *internal* parameter name.

The code inside the method is fine the way it is.
You only need to reset properties that are different for each annotation (the re-used view will have the properties set to the values that were applied after first creation).